# Vue.js wont show more than one component on screen

Tags: javascript, web, vue.js, components, vue-component

I am currently working on a vue.js application. I am using the CDN , not the CLI instalation.

I just created this component

```
Vue.component('intro', {
    template: '<div id="intro">\n' +
    '<div class="content">\n' +
    '    <img src="images\\logo.svg" alt="" id="logo">\n' +
    '<h2>Hello! My name is Juliana Villegas. I am an interactive media designer. I love mobile, web and creative development. <br> <span id="welcome">Welcome to my portafolio!</span></h2>\n' +
    '</div>\n' +
    '</div>'
})
```

And i make it appear on my html like this:

```
<div id="app">
    <intro></intro>

</div>
```

The component shows up on screen just fine, but everything else i create is not visible.

I've tried to duplicate it, and even place a simple `<p>` after the `<intro>` tag, but nothing besides that first component shows up on screen. 
I've also tried making the component position relative, and still nothing.

**Is it something related to vue, or maybe i made a mistake in the css?**
here is how the css goes to far

```
body{
    background-color: black;
    overflow: scroll;
}
#stars-container{
    z-index: 0;
}
#intro{
    z-index: 99;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}
#logo{
    width: 30vw;
margin-bottom: 5vh;
}
img{

}
h2{
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 16pt;
}
#welcome{
    font-weight: 700;
}
p{
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: `#intro{
    z-index: 99;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;}` this css selector make `#intro` full page size. scroll down then you may see the `<p>` element at the bottom. or open your browser console.

Comment: @Sphinx i know it is supposed to be the full size of the screen. The problem is that even if i duplicate the intro 4 times, it stills shows one . it doesnt let me scroll or anything. I tried inspect, and it showed me there was a '<p>' but it never highlighted anything on screen like it does with everything else

Comment: try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z7j4kemo/) which I copied your codes...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add  data to the component then you can pass data to it, such that it can displayed in it. That’s where props come in.

Props are custom attributes you can register on a component. When a value is passed to a prop attribute, it becomes a property on that component instance. To pass a title to your  component, then it can include it in the list of props this component accepts, using a props

for your problem in below way we can pass the data to the component.

Vue.component('intro', {
template: `<div id="intro"> <h4>{{title}}</h4> <div class="content"> <img src="images\\logo.svg" alt="" id="logo"> <h2>Hello! My name is Juliana Villegas. I am an interactive media  designer. I love mobile, web and creative development. <br>  <span id="welcome">Welcome to my portafolio!</span></h2> </div> </div>`,
props:['title']
});

Then after include this template in your web page in below way.

then it the page appears like this..

[This image show out put after template included in the webpage.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTyks.png)

[If you want to know more details then refer this once](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html)

Comment: include your template in your web page in this way.                                        
     <intro title="simple web page"></intro>